# Register-PSRepository throw error on Values cannot be found on object

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

After a clean install of Powershell Core (via Chocolatey) on a Windows Server.  I am unable to install a module.

```
Install-Module PSSlack
```

Returns error

> No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name

OK, let me try and register a repository

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
```

throws a null exception

```
PowerShell 7.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
PS C:\Windows\System32>  Register-PSRepository -Default
Register-PackageSource: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSMo
dule.psm1:11529
 Line |
11529 |  .     $null = PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource @PSBoundParamete
 .
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      | The property 'Values' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
      | property exists.
```

I get the same error on the Powershell ISE installed on the server.  I had hoped that a clean install of powershell core would magically fix.  Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code in your session prior to calling `Invoke-Module`:

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```